# Writing Client/Server Program in C on UNIX Server

Tags: c, unix, client-server

I am trying to write a basic C client/server program using sockets in Unix.  I am logging on my school's Unix server from my home computer.  I am logging on twice, once to simulate the server and the other to simulate the client.  Do I use AF_INET or AF_UNIX? Whose IP address should I use, the one from my home computer or my school? If I use my school's IP address, how do I find out what it is? How do I find out what port number I should use? Does the port number for my client and server have to be the same?

Comment: When you question is resolved (which this one appears to be), try to mark the answer that helped you the most as 'accepted', by clicking on the clear tick next to that answer.  It acts as an indicator to anybody that has a similar problem in the future.  More information can be found in the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

1. Usually you'll want to use `AF_INET` — then you'll be able to communicate between more than one computer later.
2. Use `127.0.0.1`; that means "this computer".
3. Make up a port number and use it for both. Usually you'll want to pick something between 1024 and 65536, exclusive.

Comment: And in this case, "this computer" would be the machine at school (i.e. the machine that everything is running on).

Answer (score 0):

Since the programs are running on the schools computer you should use that IP address.
You can use the command */usr/sbin/ifconfig -a* to find it (it's the inet address). However, if both logins are at the same physical computer (for example at my school that isn't always the case) you can just use 127.0.0.1.
You can use any port number you want, but choose a high (like four digits) since the lower ones are default for some services.
The port numbers for the client and server do not have to be the same, but it might be easier for you to remember if they are.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/textcode.html) for a lot of examples. There is some stuff you have to understand:

- TCP, UDP and the difference between them
- What is a socket, types of sockets (stream, datagram, sequential packets)
- Socket API's - BSD, POSIX, WinSock (if you're planning to program for Windows)